# How to run TensorFlow on an AWS cluster?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tensorflow

I'm trying to run distributed tensorflow on an EMR/EC2 cluster but I don't know how to specify different instances in the cluster to run parts of the code.

In the documentation, they've used `tf.device("/gpu:0")` to specify a gpu. But what if I have a master `CPU` and 5 different slaves `GPU` instances running in an EMR cluster and I want to specify those GPUs to run some code? I can't input `tf.device()` with the public DNS names of the instances because it throws an error saying the name cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question, AWS has released some code to ease the use of distributed TensorFlow on an EC2 cluster.

See this [github repository](https://github.com/awslabs/deeplearning-cfn). Everything is described in the README.md but the short story is that it will create an AWS stack with

- Security Groups
- Elastic File System
- EC2 instances with the AWS deep learning AMI and the EFS mounted on them,
- The EC2 instances will be configured so you can easily run a distributed tensorflow run by running a command on the master node (see the Running Distributed Training on TensorFlow section).